Is it possible to tree shake unused messages in vue-i18n?
My app uses define vite option to configure a feature set for the build. So, depending on the configuration, not all code base is finally in the bundle (bundles). I'm wondering is there a mechanism to tree shake unused translation messages?
All i found by search, if i understood it right, is about tree shaking of unused features, not messages.

This is possible with a bundler plugin. I didn't check if the existing one does this @intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n , it's possible that tree shaking naturally happens when messages are compiled to JS. Otherwise you'd have to write your own, though IMO it serves a better purpose to statically analyze the messages and physically remove the unused ones in order to not maintain them

Thanks for your comment! This is not a mistake that unused messages exist, at least in my project. They become unused for a particular build. I set my configuration through the define vite option (global variable replacements) and it cuts some code as a result.
